# Basic time complexity?

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, time-complexity

Consider these three loops

**O(N^2)**

```
int i = 0, s = 0;
while (2*i <= N*N) {
s+=i;
i++;
}
```

**O(N)**

```
int i = 0, s = 0;
while (s <= N*N) {
s+=i;
i++;
}
```

**O(sqrt(N))**

```
int i = 0, s=0, p=1;
while (s < N) {
i++;
p = p*i;
s += i;
}
```

The time complexity of the first is O(N^2), but the second one is O(N) (to me it seems N^2 would be more appropriate). How come? Additionally, why is loop three sqrt(N) and not log(N) - how can I tell the difference?

Comment: Triangular numbers.

Comment: So triangular number iterations upto N*N = O(N) and triangular number iterations upto N = O(sqrt(N) ?

Comment: Do I *really* need to spell this out? Consider how the n-th triangular number grows as n increases.

Comment: The third loop,, what is N? what is the use of p?

Answer (score 2):

For the second:
Let say the iterations will be `k` then the loop will be repeated for:

```
1+2+3+...k <= N^2 --> k*(k-1)/2 <= N^2 --> k^2 <= N^2 --> k is O(N).
```

For the third:
Let say the iterations will be `k` then the loop will be repeated for:

```
1+2+3...+k <= N -->...--> k^2 <= N --> k is O( sqrt(N) ).
```